# Let $G$ be the dihedral group $D_{2n}$. Let $t \in G$ correspond to a flip and $r \in G$ corresponds to a plane rotation. Show that $trt=r^{-1}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be the dihedral group $D_{2n}$. Let $t \in G$ correspond to a flip and $r \in G$ corresponds to a plane rotation. Show that $trt=r^{-1}$. Conclude that if $n$ is odd, then only the identity of $G$ commutes with all elements of $G$.

I know that in order to show equivalence, I usually show the left side is contained in the right side, and vice versa. How do I prove equality here though, for a set of actions?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*  In general,  $D_{2n}$ consists of rotations $r_0,\dots,r_{n-1}$ and reflections $s_0,\dots,s_{n-1}$ satisfying:   $r_ir_j=r_{i+j}\,,s_ir_j=s_{i-j}\,,r_is_j=s_{i+j}$
and $ s_is_j=r_{i-j}$ where addition of subscripts is done using addition modulo n.

Comment: I got to the point where I have $r_{(i-j)-i} = r_{n-j}$. From here, do I want to show that i-i=n? Which shows (i-j)-i=(i-i)-j=n-j? Or is this not associative?

Comment: Don't you just get $(i-j)-i=-j$.  And $r_{-j}=r_j^{-1}$.  Well, $n-j\cong -j\pmod n$, so I guess you have it.

Comment: I accidentally went a step too far and said said the inverse of r was $r_{n-j}$. I get it now, Thank you for your help!